# Difference between using Immediate scheduler and not using schedulers at all

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

Whats the difference between using `Immediate scheduler` and not using?

```
Observable.create(subscriber -> subscriber.onNext(new Object())).subscribeOn(Schedulers.immediate()).subscribe();
//vs
Observable.create(subscriber -> subscriber.onNext(new Object())).subscribe();
```

Immediate scheduler uses `SleepingAction` and runs it instantly:

```
this.schedule(new SleepingAction(action, this, execTime));
```

But it seems it's actually not immediate, there is possible delay:

```
long delay = this.execTime - this.innerScheduler.now();
Thread.sleep(delay);
```

So am I right that difference between using `Immediate scheduler` and not using schedulers at all is in possible delay?

Answer (score 1):

That is correct however this delaying option is not what makes Schedulers.immediate() useful

`Schedulers.immediate()` might be used for providing synchrounous variants of `Observable` with dependency injection.
For example having such class :

```
public class ServiceObservable {

    private final Scheduler subscribeOnScheduler;
    private final Scheduler observeOnScheduler;

    public ServiceObservable(Scheduler subscribeOnScheduler, Scheduler observeOnScheduler) {
        this.subscribeOnScheduler = subscribeOnScheduler;
        this.observeOnScheduler = observeOnScheduler;
    }

    public Observable<ServiceData> getServiceDataObservable() {
        return serviceDataObservable
                .observeOn(observeOnScheduler)
                .subscribeOn(subscribeOnScheduler);
    }
}
```

you may want to create this object in production code like this :

`ServiceObservable serviceObservable = new ServiceObservable(Schedulers.io(), AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());`

and in tests like this

`ServiceObservable serviceObservable = new ServiceObservable(Schedulers.immediate(), Schedulers.immediate());`

Comment: It is better to use `Schedulers.trampoline()` for unit tests. Due to the blocking-sleep in immediate there is a plan to drop it entirely from 2.x. Source: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0-(draft)

Comment: `trampoline()` also uses blocking sleeps but its advantage over `immediate` is that you can recursively schedule with it.

Comment: What blocking sleep are you referring to?